# Trying to access community list beyond "Top 5" always lands me on my user page

Tags: bug, navigation, communities-list

I frequently switch SE communities by tapping the hamburger logo and then tapping on a community name.

The initial tap gives a menu with my "Top 5" communities. If I want to visit one further down the list, it's necessary to tap "Your Communities" to get the larger list of the SE communities I've joined.

Until last week or so, tapping a community in this larger list landed on the community's home page. But now, it lands on my user page in the community.

Of course, a few more taps will get me to the list of questions, but I find the extra effort inconvenient, and if the change wasn't intended I'd like it put back.

Comment: I don't think anything has changed here. Those links from the network profile page should go to the user profile page... not the site. Is it possible that you had been looking at the full sites list instead of the list of your profiles? You are likely clicking on "Your Communities" but you should try clicking on "More Stack Exchange Communities".

Comment: @Catija No, that's not the way the "Your Communities" page behaved until very recently. The "Top 5" still go to the main page. "More Stack Exchange Communities" gives the goofy graphic with all communities varying in size.  Perhaps you meant the alphabetical list of all Communities in the menu under "more stack exchange communities".  That involves scrolling through the whole list to find the one I want.  I used to be able to navigate quickly to sites 6+.

Comment: The ones in your menu go to the home page because we assume that you don't want to go to your own profile all the time. But the "Your Communities" link goes to your network profile, which anyone can see. If I'm looking at your network profile and I click on a site, I want to go to your profile on that site - not the site itself. And that's what we do.

Comment: You can always use the edit link and make your list of sites as long as you want to make it. And reorder them if you wish, too. I have 8 sites in mine, including meta sites.

Comment: @Catija Sometimes there's an edit link, but usually not.

Comment: When is there not an edit link? The mobile view? We are getting ready to get rid of it. Most of the site is responsive so it's not really necessary to use the mobile view. Regardless, you only need to edit once, not every day or anything.

Comment: @Catija Switching sites has a weird behavior of taking you out of full site view into mobile view with not much visual difference. I guess once you finally drive a stake through mobile view's heart, that will stop happening.

Comment: @Catija The longer list actually chops off and is non scrollable. It also went back to "Top 5" very quickly.

Comment: The mobile vs full-site view is saved per site, not network wide. I don't like it but there's nothing I can do about it. I'm not sure why the change isn't persisting. How many sites did you make it?

Comment: @Catija I added 5 more.

Comment: @Catija OK, I figured it out. Definitely a UX issue. After you add a site to the list, the window is in a weird state with some of it disabled and the bottom cut off.  There isn't  a scroll bar visible, but on a touch screen you can scroll it anyway (and a scroll bar appears once you start). If you scroll enough, you will eventually find a "Save" button.